# Error : String types not allowed (at 'theme' with value ") in android studio

Tags: java, android, string

When I run android studio, I keep getting this error:

> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2321Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72321Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72321Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources
>
> C : \Users\User\Desktop\UniTools\app\build\intermediates\exploded-
>   aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.2.1\res\values\values.xml
>
> Error:(315, 5) String types not allowed (at 'theme' with value '').
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 
>   'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

```
 <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult" parent="">
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">?android:textColorHint</item>
</style>
```

Then Android Studio takes me this this code in the values.xml. Any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: Why do you have `parent=""`?

Comment: Is that the problem? I have never edited the values.xml.

Comment: That automatically returns if I take it out and run it

Comment: dont let parent ="

Comment: remove the parent attribute

Comment: "Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited" If i delete the parent="" it gets regenerated

Comment: Ah. You're running into a variation on [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=93290), where Android Studio is opening up a file that you cannot edit. If you could, please edit your question and replace your existing error listing with the entire output of your Gradle console, not just those lines.

Comment: I have seen that, I have checked my strings.xml, and there is no, ', to replace with /

Comment: Check my answer here [other similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40796407/5057093)

Answer (score 1):

edit your 'values.xml' from the explorer: find values.xml->edit in notepad-> rebuild project.

you are trying to edit the generated file so parent="" appears again and again. because you cannot edit generated file

Comment: It still seems to be changing back in Android studio? I have edited it in notepad, saved and rebuilt the application

Answer (score 0):

You assign empty value to 'theme'

I think 'theme' in styles.xml or you can search for 'theme' in xml files under 'values' folder.

then check what value you assigned for 'theme'

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. To solve it just edit the `values.xml` file in notepad and save it, then you should be good-to-go.
Go to `build/intermediates/ress/merged/debug/values`.