# Error:(315, 5) String types not allowed (at 'activity_home_' with value '')

Tags: android, xml, string

Hi I have a problem that when i want to build my app this error is heppen

```
Error:(315, 5) String types not allowed (at 'activity_home_' with value '').
```

but it is happen in values.xml that generated automatically

```
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult" parent="">
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">?android:textColorHint</item>
    </style>
```

what i can do to solve this issue.

Comment: its in appcompat v23.3.0/res/values.xml and its so long

Comment: check below answer .

Comment: this link is show exactly my problem   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635240/error-string-types-not-allowed-at-theme-with-value-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem , its an empty value for a dimen tag in dimens.xml file 

why android studio is so Confusing ?!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult" parent="">
```

Remove the `parent=""` part and re-run the app :-)

Comment: What generates it?

Comment: File under the build folder generates and should not be edited